# How can I manage separate localization files in Django

Tags: django, localization

when generating my localization files I get one file by language.
I would like to get several files, e.g. one for the country names, one for my category names and one for the rest.
How can I do that?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider splitting the models, fixtures, or wherever your strings originate, to separate applications. Each application has their own .po-file.

Answer (score 0):

That is the way Django works. `makemessages` parses all relevant files and will generate a single `.po` file in the end. If you want to change this, you'll probably need to dig into Django's source ([source of makemessages command](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py) for a start).

But what is the problem you're trying to solve here? If you want to split the `.po` files to ease maintenance, you might want to look at apps like [Rosetta](http://code.google.com/p/django-rosetta/). They provide you with a web interface to update your translations.

Django itself recently switched to [Transifex](https://www.transifex.net/) for its translations, an open platform for collaborative work.

Comment: The problem I want to solve is the reusability of part of the localized text, such as country or category names.